# Nodejs sequelize issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I'm using nodejs and sequelize and the issue is that, when trying to get the values from db everything is shown as string.

```
  let merchant_data = await Products.findAll({where:{
                        product_category_id:pr_category_id,
                        global_delivery:is_global_delivery
                    },
                    include:[
                    
                    {model:Shops,
                        
                        where:{is_home_delivery:is_home_delivery,
                        },
                     
                ],
                
              
                  
                }).then(function (result) {
                        return result
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                        return 0
                    })
```

The response body that I get is as below:

```
{
"message": "done",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "9095",
        "user_id": "21",

        "product_name": "Test Product",
        "product_desc": "Testing",
        "product_category_id": "5",
        "product_sub_category_id": "32",
        "min_order_qty": "1",
        "business_margin": "5",
        "discount_percentage": "17",
        
        "product_cities": "",
        "color_size_variant": "",
       
        "shop": {
            "user_id": "21",
            "name": "Jyotish supermarket",
            "address1": "shop no. 7 ",
            "address2": "Near signature store",
            "is_home_delivery": true
        }
       
    }
]
```

}

The expected output is as below

```
{
"message": "done",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 9095,
        "user_id": 21,

        "product_name": "Test Product",
        "product_desc": "Testing",
        "product_category_id": 5,
        "product_sub_category_id": 32,
        "min_order_qty": 1,
        "business_margin": 5,
        "discount_percentage": 17,
        
        "product_cities": "",
        "color_size_variant": "",
       
        "shop": {
            "user_id": 21,
            "name": "Jyotish supermarket",
            "address1": "shop no. 7 ",
            "address2": "Near signature store",
            "is_home_delivery": true
        }
       
    }
]
```

}

This is the product model :

```
const Products = sequelize.define('products', {
```

id: {
type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true
},

```
user_id:{
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,

},  product_images: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
}, image_url: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
},
product_name: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
},

product_desc: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
},

product_category_id: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
product_sub_category_id: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
min_order_qty: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
business_margin: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
discount_percentage: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
origin_from: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
stock: {
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
presence: {
    type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true
},
measurement_unit:{
    type:Sequelize.TEXT
},
```

},

So here the thing is that, id suppose to be in int format however on my response ,it is getting as string.
It is same for every integer values.

Don't know why everything is getting into string format

Comment: You do need to post the relevant piece of code that loads data from DB and sends it to server. The data only won't help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko hi,Ijust edited the code could you check now please

Comment: Could you plz also provide `Products` model definition.

Comment: Try to use JSON.parse(result) instead of bare result.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes I tried the JSON.parse (result) and the result was Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 and also I even tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) but no change.
I have added the product model ,could you please check that too,

Comment: Where is the "response" coming from? Is this from a console.log from above or from some web server? Also: The Model does not match the fields in the output...

Comment: If you log `console.log(JSON.stringify(merchant_data))` will it be show strings or numbers? If numbers the problem is somewhere further the pipeline. Like how you send your response back to client.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ,no it is not from console.log(),this response is from the res.send() in postman . Yes ,some of the fields are omitted in response due to confidential datas and in case of console.log(JSON.stringify(merchant_data)) ,it is in string itself.

And below method I use to send response to client
  res.status(200).send({
                        message: "done",
                      
                        data: merchant_data
                    })

Comment: Have you created DB table with Sequelize?  You have `type: Sequelize.TEXT` for most of attributes. If you create tables with Sequelize `sync`, this will generate tables with type `TEXT` in DB and return the value in String when you do `findAll`.

If you haven't created table with `sync`, check your DB's data types.

Comment: @Emma ,yes the db is created with sequelize and yes most of the type are text,however the user_id and id are type of integer /bigint .And on response ,it is in string format

Comment: Do you happen to change the type of `user_id` after you created the table?  The type will be determined when you create the table and response's type follows the type of the table attributes.  Please check the `products` table schema in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the type of the column values in model definition. I can see only id and userId are in bigInt. Rest all have text. Try changing the required fields as respective datatypes. This may solve the issue